# JavaScript function offsetLeft - slow to return value (mainly IE9)

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9, unobtrusive-javascript

I've had a hard time debugging a news ticker - which I wrote from scratch using JavaScript.

It works fine on most browsers apart from IE9 (and some mobile browsers - Opera Mobile) where it is moving very slowly.

Using Developer Tools > Profiler enabled me to find the root cause of the problem.

It's a call to `offsetLeft` to determine whether to rotate the ticker i.e. 1st element becomes the last element.

```
function NeedsRotating() {
    var ul = GetList();
    if (!ul) {
        return false;
    }
    var li = GetListItem(ul, 1);
    if (!li) {
        return false;
    }
    if (li.offsetLeft > ul.offsetLeft) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

function MoveLeft(px) {
    var ul = GetList();
    if (!ul) {
        return false;
    }
    var li = GetListItem(ul, 0);
    if (!li) {
        return false;
    }
    var m = li.style.marginLeft;
    var n = 0;
    if (m.length != 0) {
        n = parseInt(m);
    }
    n -= px;
    li.style.marginLeft = n + "px";
    li.style.zoom = "1";
    return true;
}
```

It seems to be taking over 300ms to return the value, whereas the ticker is suppose to be moving left 1 pixel every 10ms.

Is there a known fix for this?

Thanks

Comment: What property are you using to animate? left? margin-left? Show us a bit more.

Comment: Done - I think I may have gone overboard with my functions.

Comment: jquery's .animate() handles a lot of this stuff internally, so you don't have to worry about it. Worth looking into.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## DOM operations

I agree with @samccone that if `GetList()` and `GetListItem()` are performing DOM operations each time, you should try to save references to the elements retrieved by those calls as much as possible and reduce the DOM operations.

> then I can just manipulate that variable and hopefully it won't go out of sync with the "real" value by calling offsetLeft.

You'll just be storing a reference to the DOM element in a variable.  Since it's a reference, it *is* the real value.  It is the same exact object.  E.g.:

```
var li = ul.getElementsByTagName( "li" )[ index ];
```

That stores a reference to the DOM object.  You can read `offsetLeft` from that object anytime, without performing another DOM operation (like `getElementsByTagName`) to retrieve the object.

On the other hand, the following would just store the value and would not stay in sync:

```
var offsetLeft = ul.getElementsByTagName( "li" )[ index ].offsetLeft;
```

## offsetLeft

If `offsetLeft` really is a bottleneck, is it possible you could rework this to just read it a lot less?  In this case, each time you rotate out the first item could you read `offsetLeft` once for the new first item, then just decrement that value in each call to `MoveLeft()` until it reaches `0` (or whatever)?  E.g.

```
function MoveLeft( px ) {

  current_offset -= px;
```

If you want to get even more aggressive about avoiding `offsetLeft`, maybe you could do something where you read the width of each list item once, and the `offsetLeft` of the first item once, then just use those values to determine when to rotate, without ever calling `offsetLeft` again.

## Global Variables

> I think I get it... so elms["foo"] would have to be a global variable?
>
> I think really I just need to use global variables instead of calling offsetLeft every 10 ms.

You don't need to use global variables, and in fact you should avoid it -- it's bad design.  There are at least a couple of good approaches you could take without using global variables:

1. You can wrap your whole program in a closure:

   ```
   ( function () {

     var elements = {};


     function NeedsRotating() {

       ...

     }  


     function example() {

       // The follow var declaration will block access
       // to the outer `elements`

       var elements;

     }


     // Rest of your code here

   } )();
   ```

   There `elements` is scoped to the anonymous function that contains it.  It's not a global variable and won't be visible outside the anonymous function.  It will be visible to any code, including functions (such as `NeedsRotating()` in this case), within the anonymous function, as long as you don't declare a variable of the same name in your inner functions.
2. You can encapsulate everything in an object:

   ```
   ( function () {

     var ticker = {};

     ticker.elements = {};


     // Assign a method to a property of `ticker`

     ticker.NeedsRotating = function () {

       // All methods called on `ticker` can access its
       // props (e.g. `elements`) via `this`

       var ul = this.elements.list;

       var li = this.elements.list_item;


       // Example of calling another method on `ticker`

       this.do_something();

     }  ;


     // Rest of your code here


     // Something like this maybe

     ticker.start();

   } )();
   ```

   Here I've wrapped everything in an anonymous function again so that even `ticker` is not a global variable.

## Response to Comments

First of all, regarding `setTimeout`, you're better off doing this:

```
t = setTimeout( TickerLoop, i );
```

rather than:

```
t = setTimeout("TickerLoop();", i);
```

In JS, functions are first-class objects, so you can pass the actual function object as an argument to `setTimeout`, instead of passing a string, which is like using `eval`.

You may want to consider `setInterval` instead of `setTimeout`.

> Because surely any code executed in setTimeout would be out of scope of the closure?

That's actually not the case.  The closure is formed when the function is defined.  So calling the function via `setTimeout` does not interfere with the function's access to the closed variables.  Here is a simple demo snippet:

```
( function () {

  var offset = 100;


  var whatever = function () {

    console.log( offset );

  };


  setTimeout( whatever, 10 );

} )();
```

`setTimeout` will, however, interfere with the binding of `this` in your methods, which will be an issue if you encapsulate everything in an object.  The following will not work:

```
( function () {

  var ticker = {};

  ticker.offset = 100;


  ticker.whatever = function () {

    console.log( this.offset );

  };


  setTimeout( ticker.whatever, 10 );

} )();
```

Inside `ticker.whatever`, `this` would not refer to `ticker`.  However, here you can use an anonymous function to form a closure to solve the problem:

```
setTimeout( function () { ticker.whatever(); }, 10 );
```

> Should I store it in a class variable i.e. `var ticker.SecondLiOffsetLeft = GetListItem(ul, 1).offsetLeft` then I would only have to call `offsetLeft` again when I rotate the list.
>
> I think that's the best alternative to a global variable?

The key things are:

1. Access `offsetLeft` once each time you rotate the list.
2. If you store the list items in a variable, you can access their `offsetLeft` property without having to repeatedly perform DOM operations like `getElementsByTagName()` to get the list objects.

The variable in #2 can either be an object property, if you wrap everything up in an object, or just a variable that is accessible to your functions via their closure scope.  I'd probably wrap this up in an object.

I updated the "DOM operations" section to clarify that if you store the reference to the DOM object, it will be the exact same object.  You don't want to store `offsetLeft` directly, as that would just be storing the value and it wouldn't stay in sync.

However you decide to store them (e.g. object property or variable), you should probably retrieve all of the `li` objects once and store them in an array-like structure.  E.g.

```
this.li = ul.getElementsByTagName( "li" );
```

Each time you rotate, indicate the current item somehow, e.g.:

```
this.current_item = ###;

// or

this.li.current = this.li[ ### ];


// Then

this.li[ this.current_item ].offsetLeft

// or

this.li.current.offsetLeft
```

Or if you want you could store the `li` objects in an array and do this for each rotation:

```
this.li.push( this.li.shift() );

// then

this.li[0].offsetLeft
```

Comment: No, the script moves the `<li>` 1px left every 10 ms. The full script is here: http://pastebin.com/5iPXrPBU Thanks for your suggestions, I should really take a more modern approach to JavaScript. Yes `offsetLeft` is a bottleneck AFAICT. Should I store it in a class variable i.e. var `ticker.SecondLiOffsetLeft = GetListItem(ul, 1).offsetLeft` then I would only have to call `offsetLeft` again when I rotate the list.

Comment: I think that's the best alternative to a global variable? I think this is the only way given that I'm using setTimeout? Because surely any code executed in setTimeout would be out of scope of the closure?

Comment: @Chris Cannon "No, the script moves the <li> 1px left every 10 ms." But isn't 1000ms / 10 == 100px per second?  I updated my answer to address your other questions (see "Response to Comments").

Comment: Yes, but if I did that the ticker would be jumpy.

Comment: Thanks for the very comprehensive answer!

Answer (score 1):

if you dont cache your selectors  in `var li = GetListItem(ul, 1);`

then performance will suffer greatly.. and that is what you are seeing because you are firing up a new selector every 10ms

you should cache the selector in a hash like

```
elms["foo"] = elms["foo"] || selectElm(foo);

elms["foo"].actionHere(...)
```

Comment: Yeah, I spent a whole weekend coding this in JavaScript - I always try to approach programming tasks as if I was writing a library. Didn't realise that JavaScript is this slow to execute!

Comment: I guess I'll have to rewrite the whole thing using more variables and less function calls...

Comment: that is not the issue.. you need to cache selectors that is it.. and it will fix your problem, it is not that it is slow per say rather when you call an operation ever 10ms or 100 times ever second .. things are bound to get slow

Comment: I think I get it... so elms["foo"] would have to be a global variable?

Comment: I think really I just need to use global variables instead of calling offsetLeft every 10 ms. Because once I have called it once and put it in a global variable then I can just manipulate that variable and hopefully it won't go out of sync with the "real" value by calling offsetLeft.

Answer (score 1):

your code is slow because reading `offsetLeft` will force the browser to do a reflow.  the reflow is the part that is slowing you down.  the browser is typically smart enough to queue changes to reduce the number of reflows.  however, given that you want the most up to date value when access `offsetLeft`, you're forcing the browser to flush that queue and do a reflow in order to calculate the correct value for you.

without knowing all the details of what you're trying to do, it's hard to know what to recommend to improve performance.  http://www.phpied.com/rendering-repaint-reflowrelayout-restyle/ explains this problem in more detail and offers some advice about minimizing reflows.